# Angular redirect to home on refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-services

What's the best way to direct a user to the home page if they happen to refresh from any other route (or state if you're using ui-router, as I am).

For example - I want them to begin on the `inventory` page.  If they want to make edits, they travel to the `edits` page, but if they refresh that page, they go straight to the `inventory` route again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I havn't used the ui-router but in ng-route we can do it like this

- create a controller on top of your ng-view div

> ```
> <body ng-controller="topController">
> <div ng-view></div>
> </body>
> ```

- Define your routes normally but in topController just write this line

> $location.path("/")

assuming that "/" is your main page where you want to redirect after refresh, don't forget to define $location

Comment: I feel a little silly to have forgotten the outer controller of my ui-view.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{ 
  window.setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'homeURL'; }, 0); 
  window.onbeforeunload = null; 
}
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Assume that `#/inventory` is your route, use `otherwise`

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/inventory");
```

See [URL Routing - $urlRouterProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider)

Comment: "otherwise" is for invalid routes.  If a user heads over to the "edits" page, and hits refresh, they are technically on a valid route, so the otherwise will not be processed, and will not work.